# Cómo hacer que el texto llene la celda de un datagridview (explico)

Tags: vb.net

He definido la altura de las filas para que quepan unas tres líneas, pero solo se ve una linea al medio y truncada cuando es mas grande que el ancho de la columna.

Lo que deseo es que si el texto es más largo que el ancho se vea en tres líneas. Ya le di la altura pero el texto no se ajusta. ¿Cómo hago que se ajuste?